# Rails how to create a multiple choice image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to create an image uploader. Where the user can either paste an url to an image that then gets uploaded or upload a image from their local computer. And how should I validate for the Image?

How do I create this with paperclip or, some other image upload gem?

**My view:**

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @konkurrancer], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :label => 'Titel', :style => 'width:500;' %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo, :label => '125x125', :style => 'width:250;' %> or 
    <%= f.input :photo, :label => '125x125', :style => 'width:500;' %>
    <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Create item' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

here's an approach how you could realise an remote upload (and still using paperclip):

Create a class like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

# Make it always write to tempfiles, never StringIO
OpenURI::Buffer.module_eval {
  remove_const :StringMax
  const_set :StringMax, 0
}

class RemoteUpload 

  attr_reader :original_filename, :attachment_data

  def initialize(url) 
    # read remote data
    @attachment_data    = open(url)

    # determine filename
    path = self.attachment_data.base_uri.path

    # we need this attribute for compatibility to paperclip etc.
    @original_filename = File.basename(path).downcase
  end

  # redirect method calls to uploaded file (like size etc.)
  def method_missing(symbol, *args)
    if self.attachment_data.respond_to? symbol
      self.attachment_data.send symbol, *args
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

**Edit**

You could add a virtual attribute like photo_remote_url to your Model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base 

  attr_accessor :photo_remote_url

  def photo_remote_url=(url) 
    return if url.blank?
    self.photo = RemoteUpload.new(url)
  end

end
```

Comment: How should the view look like? I have tried to create an file_field for my paperclip photo and a input_field for the url, but my input_field for photo is not appearing in the view.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the part of the form with the input field ?

Comment: The input field appear but it is a file upload field

Comment: ok have you tried `f.text_field :photo` ? It would be better if you insert a new field called photo_url, like `f.text_field :photo_url`. Then you check in your controller if the :photo field is empty, then use the :photo_url field

Comment: I have tried text_field it does not work (Input is the same as text_field in simple form) I have tried to add photo_url, but gets this error undefined method `photo_url'. Should I define photo_url in my model?

Comment: I've revised my answer, see the edit how you could adapt your model to work with the photo_url

Comment: I am Max, I am getting the error: uninitialized constant Konkurrancer::RemoteUpload. I have named the class file remote_upload and it is in the lib folder, should I require 'remote_upload' in my model?

Comment: if your lib/ folder is not in the `config.autoload_paths` (see config/application.rb) then you have to manually write `require 'remote_upload'`

Comment: My file uploads fields works fine. But the url upload dosent work the form gets just rendered on submit without any error. Here is my code: http://pastie.org/1918165

Comment: hi, try it this way: http://pastie.org/1918372 I think the photo_url has a conflict with the paperclip internals so I've changed it to photo_remote_url. And you can't upload a picture AND define an url.

Comment: it still just renders the form without any error: Here is my code http://pastie.org/1920412

Comment: Now it create the item and renders my index page. I just removed validates_attachment_presence :photo from my model. But no image gets uploaded